# Sending even matrix rows using MPI_Type_vector

Tags: c++, mpi

I have matrix of size 8x8. I want to send even rows (rows with the number of 0, 2, 4, 8) to another process using MPI_Type_vector. I came up with this code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#define INITIATOR 0
#define SIZE 8

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Datatype MPI_EVEN_ROWS;
    MPI_Type_vector(SIZE / 2, SIZE, SIZE * 2, MPI_INT, &MPI_EVEN_ROWS);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_EVEN_ROWS);

    if (rank == INITIATOR) {
        int a[SIZE][SIZE];

        printf("Matrix: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                a[i][j] = rand() % 11;
                printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        MPI_Send(a, 1, MPI_EVEN_ROWS, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {
        int b[SIZE / 2][SIZE];
        MPI_Recv(b, 1, MPI_EVEN_ROWS, INITIATOR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        printf("Received matrix: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE / 2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

After executing the program I see that it is not working as expected. I recieve the same matrix, but instead of the rows with numbers 1, 3, 5, 7 there is random junk.
The example of output:

```
Matrix: 
1 0 2 3 1 9 0 2 
8 7 2 4 10 10 7 8 
2 1 4 1 3 8 1 5 
7 4 5 2 8 9 8 9 
9 8 1 8 4 0 8 1 
7 10 3 6 7 0 1 10 
1 6 9 3 3 10 8 8 
1 2 8 9 9 3 6 5 
Received matrix: 
1 0 2 3 1 9 0 2 
1408046848 64 7 0 0 0 -81026544 21851 
2 1 4 1 3 8 1 5 
2 0 969750056 32581 972617984 32581 965895305 32581
```

I was pretty sure that I'll receive only the even rows. Am I doing something wrong or I misunderstood how MPI_Type_vector works?

Oh, and I need this task to be done by using MPI_Type_vector, I know the it can be done using MPI_Type_struct without those problems.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: you can either receive `1 * MPI_EVEN_ROWS` in `int b[SIZE][SIZE]` (and only print the even rows of `b`), or receive `SIZE/2*SIZE * MPII_INT` in `int b[SIZE/2][SIZE]`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late but

I had the same problem and i got next advice - create second data type for recieve:

```
int size = 8; // Size of initial matrix 8x8
int sizeGet = 4; // for recieve even?odd rows matrix size 4x8
MPI_Datatype MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS;
MPI_Datatype MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS_RECIEVE;
MPI_Type_vector(sizeGet, size,size*2, MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS);
MPI_Type_vector(sizeGet, size, size , MPI_DOUBLE, &MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS_RECIEVE);
MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS);
MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS_RECIEVE);
```

from matrix a (8x8) we'll be sending even and odd rows to b and c matrixes (4x8) in process #0:

```
MPI_Send(a, 1, MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS,
        1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(a+8, 1, MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and recive data in other process like this:

```
MPI_Recv(b, 1, MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS_RECIEVE, 0,
        0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Recv(c, 1, MPI_EVEN_ODD_ROWS_RECIEVE, 0,
        0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

This worked for me and I hope it will work for others

Cheers